# Transfer excel column, depending on other columns value

Tags: excel

I have two excel sheets. Both have `contact` and `send` column. 
`Contact` columns have names and `send` columns have just `yes` or `no` values.

Column `contact` is populated in the both sheets. First table has unique contacts, but the second one can have some contact multiple times(multiple rows). (They have the same contacts).

`Send` column is populated in the first sheet(with unique contacts). I need to auto populate that column in the second sheet. The criteria is contact. If they are the same, value should just be copied.

Sample

```
Sheet 1:
1. contact1   yes
2. contact2   no

Sheet 2(before)
1. contact1   
2. contact1   
3. contact2
4. contact2

Sheet 2(after)
1. contact1   yes
2. contact1   yes
3. contact2   no
4. contact2   no
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `VLOOKUP` formula to do this. [Here](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1?ui=en-US&rs=en-GB&ad=GB&fromAR=1) is Microsoft's tutorial on `VLOOKUP`. Read through that and you should be able to solve your problem.

If you are still having trouble though, come back and ask :)